# Finding the ObjectId for Annotated Tags

Tags: azure, rest, azure-devops

I"m trying to get the objectID(SHa1d) of a commit. 
Is there a way to retrieve the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the `objectId` through [Refs - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/refs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#refs_tags) rest api.

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/refs?filter=tags/&api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

[image]

However, if you want to get the information of annotatedtags from the commit's response, I am afraid this is currently not possible. The commit's response currently does not contain tags information.

Here is a [uservoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/630369/rest-api-51-include-tags-in-commit-get.html) for the same issue has been submitted on Developer Community forum. You can vote and add your comments for this feedback. Our PM and Product Group are reviewing these suggestion regularly and considering take it as plan.

In addition, you can retrieve tags based on commit id from Repos-> Tags in web UI.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [Commits - Get Commits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20commits?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) API for Azure DevOps Git should serve the Commit ID as well in the response, along with retrieving git commits for a project. Check out the [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20commits?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#examples) given in the same page for looking at some sample requests and responses.

Here is one:
[image: Commits - Get Commits example]
Hope this helps!

Comment: Are you saying that the SHA1 ID and commit ID are exchangeable?

Comment: I found this documentation on get commits
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20commits?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1
and it has this thing called " searchCriteria.itemVersion.version"
which is says it refers o SHA1 ID of a commit. 

But in the sample response, I do not see a json format of that. 

Thank you

Comment: Because my main purpose is to get the response of a specific commit, and then I have to check the tag of that commit, and it seems like the only available api link is 
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/annotatedtags/{objectId}?api-version=5.1-preview.1

which requires the objectId.

and the documentation doesn't have anything about getting 

the object Id