# How to fetch the commit given tag Id using Azure DevOps REST Api?

Tags: git, azure-devops

Given a short id of a tag I would like to get the full commit Id of that tag using the Azure DevOps REST Api.

For example, given:

```
C:\Dayforce\tip [master ≡]> git lg -1 58.0.0
7b3570ec9e7 |  (tag: 58.0.0) Some commit
C:\Dayforce\tip [master ≡]> git rev-parse 58.0.0
1c9615df48f868012cbc3dbe3552d98847c86fa2
C:\Dayforce\tip [master ≡]> git lg -1 1c9615df48f
7b3570ec9e7 |  (tag: 58.0.0) Some commit
C:\Dayforce\tip [master ≡]> git rev-parse 7b3570ec9e7
7b3570ec9e7af88f7d427e3df3fc41ee1d4c6cf1
C:\Dayforce\tip [master ≡]>
```

I am interested in a REST API for Azure DevOps that when given `1c9615df48f` returns `7b3570ec9e7af88f7d427e3df3fc41ee1d4c6cf1` on this particular repository.

**EDIT 1**

The following function uses REST API to return the full commit Id given a short one:

```
filter Get-FullCommitIdByRestApi(
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)][string[]]$CommitId,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]$TeamProject,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]$RepoName
)
{
    process
    {
        $CommitId | ForEach-Object {
            $cur = $_
            if ($cur.Length -lt 40)
            {
                $FromCommitId = $cur + '0' * (40 - $cur.Length)
                $ToCommitId = $cur + 'F' * (40 - $cur.Length)
                $url = "$TfsInstanceUrl/$TeamProject/_apis/git/repositories/$RepoName/commits?$TfsApiVersion&searchCriteria.fromCommitId=$FromCommitId&searchCriteria.toCommitId=$ToCommitId&searchCriteria.`$top=2" 
                $r = (Invoke-RestMethod $url -UseDefaultCredentials).value
                if (!$r)
                {
                    throw "Commit not found: $cur"
                }
                if ($r.Count -gt 1)
                {
                    throw "Commit too short: $cur"
                }
                $cur = $r.commitId
            }
            $cur
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is it fails if I give it a short tag Id.

Comment: There's only rest api to return full commit Id  with full tag ID, but not short tag ID. According to your example above, it's easy for you to get full tag id, so I think the api is also helpful for you.  Hope my answer helps :)

Comment: The question clear states - I have the short tag Id, not the full 40 characters. The REST Api is used when there is no git repository available locally, otherwise why would I use it at all?

Comment: What's the original error message for `The problem is it fails if I give it a short tag Id.`?

Comment: No error, it just returns `{"count":0,"value":[]}`

Comment: According to [Commits-Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20commits?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1), the rest api above is used to get commits via filter(optional). The filter only supports `searchCriteria.fromCommitId `  and  `searchCriteria.toCommitId`... It's about commits only, nothing to do with tag ID.

Comment: Right, so I was hoping there was another way. But I guess you are saying - nope.

Comment: Among the available rest apis I find only the ` Annotated Tags - Get:` can return the full commit id given full tag ID, see my edited answer. I also checked the response of `GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits/{commitID}?api-version=5.1` which returns the details of one specific commit. It's strange that the response doesn't contain anything about tag. That's why I think it's impossible cause `Annotated Tags` is the only one to connect tag and commit. But it only accepts full tag ID.

Comment: I agree it's meaningless for your scenario when you don't have local repo. For this you can add a feature request [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html) to ask for adding the feature to fetch commit with short tag id. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with the following PS function:

```
function Get-RefCommitIdByRestApi(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)][ValidateSet('tag', 'head')]$kind,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]$ref,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]$TeamProject,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]$RepoName,
    [switch]$PassThru
)
{
    $FullRefName = "${kind}s/$ref"
    $url = "$TfsInstanceUrl/$TeamProject/_apis/git/repositories/$RepoName/refs?api-version=5.0&filter=$FullRefName&`$top=2"
    $r = (Invoke-RestMethod $url -UseDefaultCredentials).value | Where-Object {
        $_.name -eq "refs/$FullRefName"
    }
    if (!$PassThru -and (!$r -or ($r -is [array])))
    {
        throw "$kind not found: $ref"
    }
    $res = $r.objectId
    if ($res -and $kind -eq 'tag')
    {
        # Could be an annotated tag, in which case the returned Id is that of the tag rather than of the commit.
        # Try to access the annotated tag information
        $url = "$TfsInstanceUrl/$TeamProject/_apis/git/repositories/$RepoName/annotatedtags/${res}?api-version=5.1-preview"
        try
        {
            $r = Invoke-RestMethod $url -UseDefaultCredentials
        }
        catch
        {
            $r = $null
        }
        if ($r)
        {
            if ($r.taggedObject.objectType -ne 'commit')
            {
                throw "The tagged object type $($r.taggedObject.objectType) is not supported. Report this bug to XYZ."
            }
            $res = $r.taggedObject.objectId
        }
    }
    $res
}
```

It handles correctly both bare and annotated tags as well as regular branches.

Answer (score 1):

> Given a short id of a tag I would like to get the full commit Id of
> that tag using the Azure DevOps REST Api.

Check [Annotated Tags - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/annotated%20tags/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1):

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/annotatedtags/{objectId}?api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

The response would contain the commit tagged by this tag:

```
    ...  

    "name": "tag1",
    "objectId": "8630dxxxxxxxxxx5f8a6f1a2c8e9d55c",
    "taggedObject": {
        "objectId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "objectType": "commit"
    },
```

The `ObjectId` here refers to `ObjectId` (**Sha1Id**) of tag. So the **supported scenario** is: When given `1c9615df48f868012cbc3dbe3552d98847c86fa2` returns `7b3570ec9e7af88f7d427e3df3fc41ee1d4c6cf1` on this repository.

As for `Given a short id of a tag I would like to get the full commit Id of that tag using the Azure DevOps REST Api`, it's **not supported** for now.

Comment: That does not answer the question.

Comment: Sorry but I think the answer is not supported... If you check the rest api document you would find this, the available rest api only receives full ID. If you only have the short ID, then rest api can't return what you need for you.

Comment: The rest API does have a way to fetch the full commit Id given a short one - see EDIT 1.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Notice @mark 's comment on this answer - the suggestion below works only for simple tags (i.e. tags that created by simply "git tag  ..." command), but not for annotated tags ("git tag -a ...  ...").

Use following call:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/refs?filter=tags/{tagName}&api-version=5.0-preview.1
```

Example response:

```
{
    "value": [{
            "name": "refs/tags/tagName",
            "objectId": "42635c0000000000000000000000000000000000",
            "creator": {
                ...
            },
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/00000000-4c33-497e-b831-000000000000/_apis/git/repositories/00000000-e61c-4741-9110-000000000000/refs?filter=tags%2FtagName"
        }
    ],
    "count": 1
}
```

The commit hash is in $response.value[0].objectId.

(Based on the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59608725/2463642).

Comment: This is true only for bare tags. For annotated tags the `objectId` corresponds to the Id of the tag itself, not the commit it tags. I will post my own answer shortly.

Comment: Thanks. Most of the tags I encountered were non annotated ones, I don't know if I'm representing everyone's situation. I added a comment to clarify.